# How to Increase the pdf page width dynamically to render the HTML page with iText?

Tags: itext, html-to-pdf

I have a HTML page which contains a table which has many columns and they do not fit in screen, so one viewing the the table has to scroll left to right to see full content as width of the page is larger than screen. 
When i'm converting this HTML page to PDF the content which are not visible without scrolling are not rendered in PDF document. Is there any way we can get the HTML page width and increase the PDF page width?

Comment: There is no such thing as "HTML page width". Increasing the size of a page is easy. You can define any `Rectangle` and use it as parameter for the `Document` constructor. Your question can't be answered in its current state. Please rephrase it and explain (using clear specifications) what you mean when you say "HTML page width".

Comment: " By HTML page width I meant HTML's horizontal width".
Thanks anyway for your reply, I am able to do it now using the Rectangle.